# Error with div update $.post into $.get with jquery and duplicated div

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, html, get

I wrote this code to display when I go over #story-comments-text another div (#comments-popup) that calls an $.get request for its html code.

This part works good.

I've a problem when I call $.post request.

#comments-popup is updated by a submit button that calls $.post(). The request works good, but after the div update, when I move my mouse over it, it shows a lot of #comments-popup bottom of the first. Where is the problem? And how can I solve it? I'm still a noob with ajax. Sorry for my bad english guys!

```
    $("#story-comments-text").mouseenter(function()
{
    var popupdiv="<div id='comments-popup'></div>";
    var href = jQuery(location).attr('href');
    var newHref=href+"&comment=1";
    if($("comments-popup").is(":visible"))
    {
        $("comments-popup").remove();
    }
    $.get
    (   newHref,
        function(data)
        {
            $("#story-comments-text").append(popupdiv);
            $("#comments-popup").css("display", "none");
            $("#comments-popup").html(data);
            $("#comments-popup").fadeIn();
            $("#story-comment-submit").click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var href = jQuery(location).attr('href');
                var newHref=href+"&comment=1&addcomment=1";
                var comment=$("#story-comment-form #story-comment-form-text").val();
                $.post
                (
                    newHref,
                    {
                        "comment":comment
                    },
                    function(data)
                    {
                        if(data)
                        {
                            $("#comments-popup").remove();

                            $("#comments-popup").css("display", "none");
                            $("#comments-popup").html(data);
                            $("#comments-popup").fadeIn();
                        }

                    }
                );
            });
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if($("comments-popup").is(":visible"))
{
    $("comments-popup").remove();
}
```

to

```
if($("#comments-popup").is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#comments-popup").remove();
    }
```

just a guess, there could be more wrong.